# java android java.net.SocketTimeoutException

Tags: java, android

sometimes here I have a `java.net.SocketTimeoutException`

```
   while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(content)) != -1) {
                            baos.write(content, 0, bytesRead);
                            str = baos.toString("UTF-8");
                            System.out.println(str);
                            requestSocket.setSoTimeout(8000);
                            break;
                        }
```

In this line :

```
 while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(content)) != -1)
```

Comment: Have you added the permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` in the AndroidManifest.xml file?

Comment: @procrastinator yes I add this permission , I don't see always this exceptions sometimes it works 10 min sometimes 20 minutes , sometimes 3 min

Comment: @procrastinator Lack of that permission does not cause this exception.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a read timeout because you set an 8-second read timeout and the peer took more than 8 seconds to send data. If you don't want that, increase the read timeout. If you do want it, fix the peer.

Your code doesn't make much sense. You are setting the read timeout inside the loop, which is pointless, and you're breaking after a single read, ditto.

Answer (score 0):

Does it happen when the phone is sleeping?

I had a similar problem months ago and the issue was related to the "doze" feature.

https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html

> Doze reduces battery consumption by deferring background CPU and network activity for apps when the device is unused for long periods of time. App Standby defers background network activity for apps with which the user has not recently interacted.

It has been added since Android > 6.X

https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2015/10/how-google-cloud-messaging-handles-doze.html

> Android 6.0 Marshmallow introduces a new power saving feature called ‘Doze’. A device enters Doze when the user leaves it unplugged and stationary for a period of time and with the screen off. When this happens, the system defers application activity to save power. It will periodically and briefly resume normal operations, called an idle maintenance window, in order to perform app syncing and other pending operations.